# Join with between condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have 2 different tables. Table 1 consists data of some activity in certain gps location detected by **latitude** and **longitude**. Table 2 consists the range of **"grid"** with shape of rectangle on certain size.

Each data from Table 1 should be **identified** in Table 2 by using latitude and longitude. Example:

Table 1 data:

| ID | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 0.05 | 120.25 |

Table 2 data:

| ID | Latitude_Upper | Latitude_Bottom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lt1 | 0.07 | 0.03 |

The result should be join table of both Table 1 and Table 2 by compile any combination of Latitude from Table 1 should be **inside** or **between** Latitude_Upper and Latitude_Bottom of Table 2

Result:

| Table1.ID | Table1.Latitude | Table1.Longitude | Table2.ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 0.05 | 120.25 | Lt1 |

So far my understanding is that **inner join** should be capable on doing this, but limited by its function when join both table, while I need to set the condition for the Latitude.

```
select a.*, b.id from Table1 as a
inner join Table2 as b
on a.latitude > b.latitude_bottom and a.latitude < b.latitude_upper
```

Of course, the script is not worked as I expected. Currently, I stuck on how to this. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: lat/long are just a point , how one point can be inside another point , they are not area

Comment: your query is work completely as expected, what's your problem? here is a demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb7e51/3 and you can change the last line with `on a.latitude between b.latitude_bottom and b.latitude_upper`

Comment: @eshirvana he said that Table2 is consists of possible ranges, although a range for `Latitude` doesn't define a `rectangle` area, he should consider `Longitude (upper & bottom)` as well to create a `rectangle` area

Comment: hi @Shahroozevsky the result in SQL di duplicated as much as number of variation of table b, which also the same from the demo if I add more data for table 2

Comment: @RandyAdhitama just wait for moment, look at this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14b149/1 is the query result wrong?

Comment: hi @Shahroozevsky after seen the 2nd demo it was right, I think I have confused with some logic for this case. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

This question is answering itself. We just need to know whether a point (consist of Latitude and Longitude) is in a given range for some area. 
Although to form a rectangle in space we need four points :

- Latitude Upper Limit
- Latitude Bottom Limit
- Longitude Upper Limit
- Longitude Bottom Limit

but here we just need to check boundaries for Latitude.
The query is completely true. When we use inner join on two tables, we can use any possible equality or inequality phrases in join clause.
So the query is as follows

```
SELECT a.*, b.id 
FROM Table1 AS a
INNER JOIN Table2 AS b
ON a.latitude > b.latitude_bottom AND a.latitude < b.latitude_upper
```

And here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14b149/1)

Answer (score -2):

You can try this,
But remember about query cost

- If the Table2  is having only single record

  SELECT a.* FROM Table1

  WHERE a.latitude > (SELECT latitude_bottom FROM Table2)
  AND a.latitude < (SELECT latitude_upper FROM Table2)
- If the Table2  is having only multiple record

  SELECT a.* FROM Table1

  WHERE a.latitude > (SELECT MAX(latitude_bottom) FROM Table2)
  AND a.latitude < (SELECT MIN(latitude_upper) FROM Table2)

Comment: generally how can you say that `a1` is belong to `Lt1` ?  and about second list item: why select `max` and `min` of `Table2` ? what is the point of that? and one more thing: do you run these queries yourself? do they work as expected?

Comment: 1. No I have not run them cause if I want to I have to create the table. So queries are merely prototypes. 
2. usage of max and min if we there is more than one range is available. I just gave the idea, actually query can be designed if with original data model and data